# Electron cannot execute c++ library (libpcap) through node_api

Tags: c++, node.js, electron, node-api

I am trying to use pcap(libpcap library in Linux) in Electron through NodeJS's node_api.
The key code block in C++ is followed.

```
static napi_value RunCallback(napi_env env, const napi_callback_info info)
{
    char errBuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    //network device name
    char *devName = "wlo1";

    pcap_t *device = pcap_open_live(devName, 65535, 1, 0, errBuf);
    .......
}
```

The binding.gyp:

```
{ 
 "targets":[
    {
      "target_name":"net",
      "sources": [ "./code/net.cpp" ],
       "libraries": [
            "-lpcap"
        ],
    }
  ]
}
```

The log is here:

```
> my-electron-app@1.0.0 start
> electron .

Error: wlo1: You don't have permission to capture on that device (socket: 不允许的操作)
```

I tried using **sudo -E npm start**, but it didn't work for me.
However I can simply run code like **pcap_open_live()** in a single file compiled by g++, like **sudo ./test**. So I wonder if there is any setting I should do in Electron or Node.JS, like in binding.gyp or js files?

Comment: Did that error message originate from the native module that you compiled or it came from somewhere else?

Comment: Run **node-gyp configure build**  is ok. And I run **npm start** , no problem. But when my electron app starts through npm start and running the code I mentioned above , it shows the message above.

Answer (score 0):

**This might help:**

> `sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /path/to/your-app`

This command grants the CAP_NET_RAW and CAP_NET_ADMIN capabilities to your Electron application, allowing it to capture network packets.